# Showing partial number of elements in a scrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

**Objective:** to list partial number of elements in a list, showing more elements only if user want to. For example, **oriList** is a list that contains 38 elements, by default there will be only first 20 elements being show, when button "Show More" being clicked, the remaining 18 elements will be showed.

**Requirement:** Each of the element have to be included as a row in a tableLayout that implementing scrollView.

May I know how can I achieve my objective?

Comment: `"Each of the element have to be included as a row in a tableLayout that implementing scrollView. "` This confuses me ... `TableLayout` extends `LinearLayout`, while `ScrollView` extends `FrameLayout`. Did you meant to say you have a `TableLayout` in a `ScrollView`? Wouldn't it be simpler if you would have a `ListView`?

Comment: I'm sorry that I confused you. Yes I meant TableLayout in a ScrollView. I need to have that button to be dynamic. For example, when it first showing 20 rows, the button "Show More" is at 21st row, and when the user click on it, the list showing all 38 rows and the button is now at 39th row..Can this be achieve by using ListView as I have zero idea about listview

Comment: It would be actually a lot easier and way more efficient.